# Jquery - Clickable object on a Clickable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I have a **clickable** object on a **clickable** object like this

[image]

> The cross mark have bigger z-index.

```css
 .close {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-left: 323px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 5px;
   } //cross mark

.quickmode_block{
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) no-repeat scroll 16px 16px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
```

```
<div style="margin-top:-7%" id="add_quicksetup" style="height:100px;width:500px;margin-top:0%;margin-right:0%;position: relative" class="quickmode_block">
                <div class="close">
                </div>
                <center style="margin-top:20px"><font size="5" style="margin-left:-14%;">Add Quick Mode</font></center>
            </div>
```

I use jquery `.click` DOM. But somehow when I click it, it still trigger the both. Is there any solution for this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         $('#add_quicksetup_confirm').click(function() {
                    //some event;
                });

            });
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.close').click(function() {
                    //some event;
                });

            });
```

Comment: Could you add your JS/jQuery code to the question too. Sounds like you need a `stopPropagation()` call

Comment: I thought a bigger z-index would just block the smaller z-index?

Comment: z-index will not do the job, you need to stop event propagation, check my answer, hope it will help

Comment: @Pwan css doesn't affect on event behavior

Comment: I dont know why when my mouse click on cross mark. It does change the hover effect. but the cross mark doesn't do anything. Is it because of my css position?

Comment: @Pwan let me know if it worked

Comment: it still cant be clicked.. just don't know why. I have already disabled all others jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.stopPropagation()

```
$('#add_quicksetup').on('click', function(e){
   alert('add_quicksetup');
})

$('.close').on('click', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('close');
})
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chzo52w3/) for you

Comment: but when I click the cross mark the #add_quicksetup will still be trigger.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
  $('.close').click(function(event) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                //some event;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For stop propogation event on parent elemnt you can `return false;` from child element event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#add_quicksetup_confirm').click(function() {
             //some event;
         });
         $('.close').click(function() {
             //some event;
             return false;
        });
});
```

or you can use `stopPropagation()` method of event object

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#add_quicksetup_confirm').click(function() {
             //some event;
         });
         $('.close').click(function(e) {
             e.stopPropagation();
             //some event;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your css. Both the divs ('close button' div and 'Add quick mode' dive) are overlapping with each other. So change css style for close button/x-mark with following :

```
.close {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: right !important;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 50;
}
```